# unable to insert data using custom action by belongs with has many relationship rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, relationship

My relationships are:

```
class PrivateClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lesson_plans
end

class LessonPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :private_class
end
```

My form is like:

```
<%= form_tag (add_lesson_plan_teacher_teacher_private_school_private_class_path), remote: true do %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag :title, nil, :class => "control-label" %>
          <%= text_field_tag "private_class[lesson_plan][title]", "", class: "form-control first_input", required: true, style: "width: 210%;" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag :description, nil, :class => "control-label" %>
          <%= text_area_tag "private_class[lesson_plan][description]", "", placeholder: "Enter Description Here", class: "form-control", rows: "3", required: true, style: "width: 210%;" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag :notes, nil, :class => "control-label" %>
          <%= text_area_tag "private_class[lesson_plan][notes]", "", placeholder: "Enter Notes Here", class: "form-control", rows: "3", required: true, style: "width: 210%;" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= submit_tag "Create lesson plan", :class => "btn btn-info" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class Teacher::PrivateClassesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_teacher
  before_action :set_private_school
  before_action :set_private_class

  def add_lesson_plan
    @lesson_plan = @private_class.lesson_plans.new(private_class_params).save
  end

  private

  def private_class_params
    params.require(:private_class).permit!
  end

  def set_teacher
    @teacher = Teacher.friendly.find(params[:teacher_id])
  end

  def set_private_school
    @private_school = PrivateSchool.friendly.find(params[:private_school_id])
  end

  def set_private_class
    @private_class = PrivateClass.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

routes are:

```
resources :private_schools do
        resources :private_classes do
          member do
            get :lesson_plan
            post :lesson_plan
            post :add_lesson_plan
          end
        end
      end
```

Now the problem is that when I try to insert data in lesson plans table it says:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'lesson_plan' for LessonPlan.):
  app/controllers/teacher/private_classes_controller.rb:11:in `add_lesson_plan'
```

What I need to do is enter the lesson plan fields data into lesson plan table with private_class_id
If anything wrong please correct me.

**UPDATE**

here are the results of puts statement:

```
def add_lesson_plan
    puts params.inspect, '++++++++++++++++++++++++'
    puts @private_class.lesson_plans.new.inspect, '**************************************'
    @lesson_plan = @private_class.lesson_plans.new(private_class_params).save!
  end

{"utf8"=>"✓", "private_class"=>{"lesson_plans"=>{"title"=>"ggd", "description"=>"gghh", "notes"=>"gggkd"}}, "commit"=>"Create lesson plan", "controller"=>"teacher/private_classes", "action"=>"add_lesson_plan", "teacher_id"=>"carmel-cynthia", "private_school_id"=>"dr-jasmine-e-mcnair-high-school", "id"=>"1"}
++++++++++++++++++++++++
#<LessonPlan id: nil, title: nil, description: nil, notes: nil, subject_id: nil, teacher_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, is_private: true, is_publish: false, user_id: nil, publish_date: nil, popularity_count: 0, is_special: false, private_class_id: 1>
**************************************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params`:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "private_class"=>{"lesson_plans"=>{"title"=>"ggd", "description"=>"gghh", "notes"=>"gggkd"}}, "commit"=>"Create lesson plan", "controller"=>"teacher/private_classes", "action"=>"add_lesson_plan", "teacher_id"=>"carmel-cynthia", "private_school_id"=>"dr-jasmine-e-mcnair-high-school", "id"=>"1"}
```

the `private_class_params` method is probably returning:

```
{"lesson_plans"=>{"title"=>"ggd", "description"=>"gghh", "notes"=>"gggkd"}}
```

but you actually need the content of `lesson_plans`, so change it to:

```
def private_class_params
  params.require(:private_class).permit![:lesson_plans]
end
```

or adjust your form to post it in the expected shape ;)

**EDIT**

`params.require(:private_class).permit!` returns the content of `private_class` key, which is a hash... then `[:lesson_plans]` return the content of `lesson_plans` key in that hash, which are the attributes you need to create your object...

You can try the following in your console to understand it:

```
params = {"utf8"=>"✓", "private_class"=>{"lesson_plans"=>{"title"=>"ggd", "description"=>"gghh", "notes"=>"gggkd"}}, "commit"=>"Create lesson plan", "controller"=>"teacher/private_classes", "action"=>"add_lesson_plan", "teacher_id"=>"carmel-cynthia", "private_school_id"=>"dr-jasmine-e-mcnair-high-school", "id"=>"1"}
#=> {"utf8"=>"✓", "private_class"=>{"lesson_plans"=>{"title"=>"ggd", "description"=>"gghh", "notes"=>"gggkd"}}, "commit"=>"Create lesson plan", "controller"=>"teacher/private_classes", "action"=>"add_lesson_plan", "teacher_id"=>"carmel-cynthia", "private_school_id"=>"dr-jasmine-e-mcnair-high-school", "id"=>"1"}
params['private_class'] # similar to the result of your private_class_params method
#=> {"lesson_plans"=>{"title"=>"ggd", "description"=>"gghh", "notes"=>"gggkd"}}
params['private_class']['lesson_plans'] # the attributs you actually need
#=> {"title"=>"ggd", "description"=>"gghh", "notes"=>"gggkd"}
```

Comment: If you dont mind could you please explain the `[:lesson_plans]`? And also please add the source of ruby doc as well. :) I mean what exactly `[:lesson_plans]` is doing?

Comment: Thanks so much. You really made my day. :) Stay Blessed. I wish I could give you 10 UPs.